# Is there a RegEx to remove the first instance of "."?

Tags: regex, regex-group, alteryx

I am trying to remove the first dot "." from a sequence of numbers like this: `2500155978.06.` intending to have `250015597806.`

Typically, I try to only match what I need and substitute later, i.e. match all "." and then remove the first match. I have been trying with `^[^.]+` but I am only getting the digits up to the first "."

Thought about using a capture group with a positive lookahead but it got me nowhere (still learning RegEx).

Thank you in advance for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(\d+)\.
```

and replace with `$1`, the placeholder pointing to the value stored in Group 1.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DNWOik/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (later referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): one or more digits
- `\.` - a dot.